# How to accomplish this Bootstrap layout without duplicating content?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to figure out how to accomplish a certain Bootstrap layout without duplicating content. Basically, I would like to have some content broken into 2 columns at the `sm`/`md` breakpoints and then 3 columns for the `lg` breakpoint.

For `sm`/`md` the layout would be like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      Item 1<br/>
      Item 2<br/>
      Item 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      Item 4<br/>
      Item 5<br/>
      Item 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And then on the `lg` breakpoint I want it to look like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Item 1<br/>
      Item 2
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Item 3<br/>
      Item 4
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      Item 5<br/>
      Item 6
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now I know that I could accomplish this by duplicating content and using `hidden`/`visible` classes to only show certain items at certain breakpoints but I was wondering if it is possible to accomplish this without duplicating content.

I also know that I could just set all 3 columns to `col-lg-6` and the 3rd column would fall right below the first one, but I was hoping to have the items within the columns equally distributed so they are the same height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap allows you to specify multiple `col-*-*` breakpoints.  A single column could have (for example) `col-sm-3 col-md-4 col-lg-6` and Bootstrap will apply the appropriate sizing based on the viewport width.

For your needs, you could use something along the lines of:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">Item 1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">Item 2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">Item 3</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">Item 4</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">Item 5</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4">Item 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So we're telling Bootstrap that if XS, SM, or MD are valid the column width is 6/12 and if LG is valid we are using a column width of 4/12.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for, very clever, thank you!